# how to start a for loop in R programming

Tags: r

I'm new to programming and I wrote a code that finds spam words for the first email but I would like to write a for loop that would do this for all of the emails. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
words = grepl("viagra", spamdata[[ 1 ]]$header[ "Subject"])
```

Comment: Have you looked at the 'An Introduction to R' manual that came with your  installation?

Comment: There are a number of ways to accomplish what you're looking for, with for loops being one of the least efficient ways of doing it. When reading the manual Dirk suggested watch out for phrases such as vectorization and apply functions.

Comment: I hope this isn't for a class project.  I know of a few people who use that spam data...

Answer (score 15):

I presume that you want to loop over the elements of `spamdata` and build up an indicator whether the string `"viagra"` is found in the subject lines of your emails.

Lets set up some dummy data for illustration purposes:

```
subjects <- c("Buy my viagra", "Buy my Sildenafil citrate",
              "UK Lottery Win!!!!!")
names(subjects) <- rep("Subject", 3)
spamdata <- list(list(Header = subjects[1]), list(Header = subjects[2]),
                 list(Header = subjects[3]))
```

Next we create a vector `words` to hold the result of each iteration of the loop. You do not want to be growing `words` or any other object at each iteration - that will force copying and will slow your loop down. Instead allocate storage before you begin - here using the length of the list over which we want to loop:

```
words <- logical(length = length(spamdata))
```

You can set up a loop as so

```
## seq_along() creates a sequence of 1:length(spamdata) 
for(i in seq_along(spamdata)) {
    words[ i ] <- grepl("viagra", spamdata[[ i ]]$Header["Subject"])
}
```

We can then look at `words`:

```
> words
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Which matches what we know from the made up subjects.

Notice how we used `i` as a place holder for `1`, `2`, and `3` - at each iteration of the loop, `i` takes on the next value in the sequence `1`,`2`,`3` so we can i) access the `i`th component of `spamdata` to get the next subject line, *and* ii) access the `i`th element of `words` to store the result of the `grepl()` call.

Note that instead of an implicit loop we could also use the `sapply()` or `lapply()` functions, which create the loop for you but might need a bit of work to write a custom function. Instead of using `grepl()` directly, we can write a wrapper:

```
foo <- function(x) {
    grepl("viagra", x$Header["Subject"])
}
```

In the above function we use `x` instead of the list name `spamdata` because when `lapply()` and `sapply()`  loop over the `spamdata` list, the individual components (referenced by `spamdata[[i]]` in the `for()` loop) get passed to our function as argument `x` so we only need to refer to `x` in the `grepl()` call.

This is how we could use our wrapper function `foo()` in `lapply()` or `sapply()`, first `lapply()`:

```
> lapply(spamdata, foo)
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE
```

`sapply()` will simplify the returned object where possible, as follows:

```
> sapply(spamdata, foo)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Other than that, they work similarly.

Note we can make our wrapper function `foo()` more useful by allowing it to take an argument defining the spam word you wish to search for:

```
foo <- function(x, string) {
    grepl(string, x$Header["Subject"])
}
```

We can pass extra arguments to our functions with `lapply()` and `sapply()` like this:

```
> sapply(spamdata, foo, string = "viagra")
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> sapply(spamdata, foo, string = "Lottery")
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Which you will find most useful (`for()` loop or the `lapply()`, `sapply()` versions) will depend on your programming background and which you find most familiar. Sometimes `for()` is easier and simpler to use, but perhaps more verbose (which isn't always a bad thing!), whilst `lapply()` and `sapply()` are quite succinct and useful where you don't need to jump through hoops to create a workable wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

In R a loopstakes this form, where variable is the name of your iteration variable, and sequence is a vector or list of values:

for (variable in sequence) expression

The expression can be a single R command - or several lines of commands wrapped in curly brackets:

```
for (variable in sequence) { 
    expression
    expression
    expression
}
```

In this case it would be for(words){ do whatever you want to do}

**Also**

Basic loop theory

The basic structure for loop commands is: `for(i in 1:n){stuff to do}`, where n is the number of times the loop will execute.

`listname[[1]]` refers to the first element in the list “listname.”

In a for loop, `listname[[i]]` refers to the variable corresponding to the ith iteration of the for loop.

The code `for(i in 1:length(yesnovars))` tells the loop to execute only once for each variable in the list.

> Answer taken from the following
>   sources:
>   [Loops in R](http://dataninja.wordpress.com/2006/02/01/lists-in-r/)
>   [Programming in R](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/degrees/modules/ch923/r_introduction/r_programming/)

Comment: Second part is verbatim copy from http://dataninja.wordpress.com/2006/02/01/lists-in-r/

Comment: First part is verbatim copy from http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/degrees/modules/ch923/r_introduction/r_programming/

Comment: I hope to win the loopstakes soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot Will for adding the original sources!

Comment: Winchester: What does loopstakes mean?

Comment: -1 Incorrect answer, `n` is not the number of times the loop will execute: `for(i in 1:0){print(i)}`.